# how can I have my you tube music playlists available to play on my galaxy xcover even when I have no Internet connection?

Tags: samsung

Can I have a play list transfered from my you tube account on to my actual phone to use when I have no Internet connection?  What do I have to do? - im a tech no spaz!-please help me thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no possibility of using youtube without an internet connection.
Youtube doesn't even allow you to play music and such wil the screen is off.

You would need to have a playlist on your phone in order to play a bunch of songs.